# How to grep an XML file?

Tags: unix, gnu

In GNU, how do I grep an XML file? The scenario:

```
<HelloOperation>
    <Request>Lemon</Request>
</HelloOperation>
<HelloOperation>
    <Request>Banana</Request>
</HelloOperation>
<HelloOperation>
    <Request>Orange</Request>
</HelloOperation>
<DifferentOperation>
    <Request>Banana</Request>
</DifferentOperation>
```

Any idea how I will grep this such that I will only get the **banana** inside **HelloOperation** and *not in DifferentOperation*? Say for instance I cannot use awk.

Comment: you can get the specific result for this question using `sed`, but it will quickly break down when you start trying to "query" real xml data. Awk will be a little better, but xml requires an xml tool. If you expect to be doing anything bigger than your question above, then you have to start planning time to learn how to use `xmllint`, or an xml library for perl, python, java, etc,etc OR as mentioned below, `xmlstarlet`. Good luck! (Incidentally, this is a question that comes up every day here on S.O. Did you spend any time looking at existing questions?)

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`xmlstartlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)? You can select node using XPath.

```
$ cat 1.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <HelloOperation>
        <Request>Lemon</Request>
    </HelloOperation>
    <HelloOperation>
        <Request>Banana</Request>
    </HelloOperation>
    <HelloOperation>
        <Request>Orange</Request>
    </HelloOperation>
    <DifferentOperation>
        <Request>Banana</Request>
    </DifferentOperation>
</root>
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v './/HelloOperation/Request' 1.xml
Lemon
Banana
```